# Play sound in both speaker and headset wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, speaker, soundplayer, headphones

I have an wpf application and i am using the soundPlayer class to play sound (for eg ringtone). Currently the tone plays either on speakers or on the headset (if its plugged in).
I would like the application to play the tone on speaker even when the headsets are plugged in. I know there are ways to do this in android, but couldn't find any in wpf. Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Sharing sample code :

```
  public void detectDevices()
    {
        int waveOutDevices = WaveOut.DeviceCount;
        switch (waveOutDevices)
        {
            case 1:
                var wave1 = new WaveOut();
                wave1.DeviceNumber = 0;
                playSound(0); 

                break;
            case 2:
                var wave2 = new WaveOut();
                wave2.DeviceNumber = 0;
                playSound(0);

                var wave3 = new WaveOut();
                wave3.DeviceNumber = 1;
                playSound(1); 

                break;

        }
    }

    public void playSound(int deviceNumber)
    {
        disposeWave();// stop previous sounds before starting
        waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(fileName);
        var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
        waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        output = waveOut;
        output.Init(waveReader);
        output.Play();
    }

    public void disposeWave()
    {
        if (output != null)
        {
            if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                output.Stop();
                output.Dispose();
                output = null;
            }
        }
        if (wave != null)
        {
            wave.Dispose();
            wave = null;
        }
    }

case eSelector.startIncomingRinging:

                fileName = ("Ring.wav");
                detectDevices();
```

Answer (score 3):

My answer assumes you are using multiple output devices from your computer and not just the headphone jack available on your speakers.

`SoundPlayer` always plays using the default output device with no way to change it. One alternative would be to use a library such as [`NAudio`](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) which offers more options.

[This article](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/naudio-audio-output-devices.html) offers code examples of how to change the audio output device using NAudio.

Your question could be satisfied by making use of multiple `WaveOut` instances.

```
var waveOut1 = new WaveOut();
waveOut1.DeviceNumber = 0; // First device

var waveOut2 = new WaveOut();
waveOut2.DeviceNumber = 1; // Second device
```

The total number of devices can be retrieved from `WaveOut.DeviceCount`.

Comment: Thank you Lukazoid for suggesting Naudio but i think i am a step away from making it work. Please have a look at the edited question. Suggestions welcome.